# json_encode returns null for %E5

Tags: php

I am unable to figure out how to keep this text as-is.

```
$text = $_POST['data'];
print_r(json_encode($text));
```

I've tried all the various techniques like utf8 encoding etc. But most of them simply strip it or convert $text to some symbol. So it becomes only "test" or "SYMBOLtest". I want it to be "%E5test".  I want to keep it as is after json_encode.

**UPDATE**

It only happens with form post. So a form like:

```
<form action="test.php/" method="post">         
<textarea name="data" class="textarea"></textarea>      
<input type="submit">       
</form>
```

Now enter '%E5test' and on form submission, you will get null

Comment: This is not a duplicate of other questions as they require utf8 encoding.

Comment: well I just tested and seems like I am getting "%E5test"

Comment: can't reproduce with php 5

Comment: And why are you using `print_r()` on `json_encode()`? It is a string.

Comment: Seems to happen only with form post